# Scroll-up button Android

Tags: android, xml, button, kotlin

I have small problem. I have in layout scrollView with TextViews, now i have to set button to scroll up scrollView, but i don't know how to set well imageButton in my layout. This is my schema.

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCNf1.png)

I have to set this imageButton in place, where i show in schema, TextView5 is veeery long, and when it start scrolling the imageButton should start be visible, before scrolling it should be invisible.

To scroll it up i'm using code:

```
buttonScrollTop.setOnClickListener {
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP)
        }
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundWhite">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text3"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/text4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="@string/bigstringtext5" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonScrollTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text6" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But now imageButton is under TextView5 ;/ 
I don't know how to set it like in schema.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Use `ImageButton` in Parent Layout (RelativeLayout) outside the `ScrollView` with `alignParentBottom="true"` & `alignParentEnd="true"` and then give your ImageButton margins to make it perfect.

Comment: It works, but don't make it invisible at start, do you know how make it invisible at start and visible when start scrolling? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with the following code - it will show the image button on the right side corner as you defined in the schema.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundWhite">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/text2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:justificationMode="inter_word"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/text4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:justificationMode="inter_word"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="@string/bigstringtext5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:justificationMode="inter_word"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageButton
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:id="@+id/buttonScrollTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

**To make the button visible when the scroll view reached the bottom**

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver()
   .addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            if (scrollView.getChildAt(0).getBottom()
                 <= (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY())) {
                //scroll view is at bottom
        //set the button visibility to visible here
            } else {
                //scroll view is not at bottom
        //set the button visibility to gone here
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, this is this what i needed ! Thank you ! 
But the imageButton is all time visible i wanna to make it at start invisible and when start scrolling make it visible :) 
Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Check the answer now! Upvote it if your problem got solved! Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to change from java for Kotlin, but it doesn't work ;/

Comment: Copy and paste the above java code in your kotlin file, then android studio itself show a dialog asking to convert to kotlin.

Comment: Ok i made it! 
Thanks :)

Comment: I a little changed your code because it was hide when i was scrolling but now i don't know how to do it:
When i back to the top it again should be invisible 
Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! ✅

Comment: Last question, how  in "if" detect that, the scrollView is on top ?

Comment: If scrollY() returns 0, then it was at top. Check using if statement inside the onScollChanged() method.

Comment: Right i made it that:
if (scrollView.scrollY == 0) {
                    buttonScrollTop.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                } 
Again thank you very much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a bug now. I have function in Fragment 1, but this gave a problem in Fragment 3. I show all structure of problem in schema.

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nsvu.png)

When i have in Activity

```
viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = 1
```

than when i turn on Fragment 3 who also have scrollView i got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: scrollView1 must not be null
```

When i change like that

```
viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = 2(3,4,5 + etc)
```

Than when i turn on Fragment 3, if there is big string i have lag for 1-2 seconds, later i can scroll. If string is small i don't have this problem. 
Have any one idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try to load the string with show more...and post the code that you've tried.